# Android совет по использованию элементов

Tags: android

Использую в своем проекте Navigation Drawer Fragment.
На одном fragmente (Product) необходимо расположить информацию по группам (общая информация, экран, железо и т.д) Как лучше такую информацию расположить?

Почитав, понял что можно использовать TabLayout.

Вопрос такой: при перелистывании между вкладками информацию нужно подгружать из базы данных каждый раз по кусочкам (что принадлежит общей информации, что экрану и т.д) или данные можно как-то подгрузить на 1 вкладки, и без задержек(связанную с загрузкой данных) перелистывать между вкладками?

Какими еще способами можно отобразить информацию по группам?

Можно ли как нибудь реализовать, чтобы у всех вкладок было общее поле (например верхнее), а менялась только область от середины и до низа с помощью вкладок? Может можно это с помощью Fragmentов сделать

Comment: Уточните про "информацию по группа" или приведите пример.

Comment: Ну например Смарфон можно поделить на такие группы: Экран (Диагональ, Тип матрицы, разрешение, Плотность точек и т.д),Структура (материал, цвет, размеры, вес,), Мощность и оборудование (Процессор, графика, RAM, ROM, сенсоры), Камера (Разрешение, режимы съемки) Передача данных (Частоты связи, WIFI, Bluetooth) и т.д

Comment: И у каждый тако может подразделяться на более мелкую информацию

Comment: может есть возможность по нажатию элемента, открывалась бы область ниже, и по повторному нажатию, эта область скрывалась бы. Наподобие меню и подменю в веб

Comment: Посмотрите `ExpandableListView`

Comment: А вот при открытии этого элемента можно просто использовать область? Просто как я понял внутри их лежат ListView, что мне не нужно

Comment: Вы можете положить в внутренний `ListView` 1 фрагмент и все будет работать.

Comment: Или придумать другой способ отображения.

Comment: может recyclerview с expand подойдет